# Visual Studio Express 2013 for windows - develop Windows Phone apps - Is that all that is required?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I want to develop an app for Windows Phone.

Is Visual Studio Express 2013 for windows all that I need to develop and upload?

Is there any other fee required or something to pay?

Thanks

Comment: http://dev.windows.com/en-us -- seems the headline answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows (Update 3) running on Windows 8.1 is sufficient to develop an app for Windows Phone. To upload it to the store you will also need a Dev Center subscription, which is a one-time fee of about US$20 and gives access to both the Windows Store and Windows Phone Store.

See [Account types, locations, and fees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj863494.aspx) for the list of account types and fees for each country. You can sign up at http://dev.windows.com/en-us/dashboard

--Rob